# Create a class that is the "same" as another class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, model

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.10 and I would like to create a new class\model *Class2* that has the same behavior (methods, constants, ...) and that is related to the same database table and ... of a class\model *Class2*. That is, **the *Class2* must be exactly the same as the *Class1***.

**How can I do that?**

---

**Motivations**

1. I would like to do that because I have the *Class1* (and a related database table) that is used to store some association data (`:has_many` and `:belongs_to`) and exactly the same associations can be handled also by the *Class2* in a equal way as the *Class1* makes.
2. Also, I would like to do that because I would "organize" application files keeping the "Ruby on Rails Way" of make things. That is, I would like to create related view files in a separated folders for both the *Class1* and the *Class2* (maybe, it is just my "standardize things mania"!).

**What about my motivations in order to create the new Class1?**

---

**What problems could I have in future developments?**

Comment: If "Class2 must be exactly the same as the Class1" then what's the point? I don't understand why you'd want two classes with the same methods and the same table.

Comment: @mu is too short - The "Motivations" paragraph should answer your question.

Comment: Why are you not satisfied with @Nexerus's answer?

Comment: @KandadaBoggu - Because there are some other questions to answer.

Comment: You can have inherited class and get the features listed in motivations. You can have two separate view directories for each class. So why would it not address your requirements?

Answer (score 4):

You want to *extend* the class? this should do the trick:

```
class MoreUsers < Users
  set_table_name "users"
end
```

Hope this is the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Extend class:

```
class Class2 < Class1
end
```